# How to kill Linux process with Python

Tags: python, linux, process

I want to automate capturing logs from serial port with 2 functions:

1) trigger to start capture

2) trigger to stop

First looks like

```
def start_capture_output():
  file = '/home/test/Desktop/log.txt'
  os.system('touch %s' % file)
  os.system('chmod +rwx %s' % file)
  os.system('cat </dev/ttyUSB0>%s' % file)
```

and it works, but I wonder how to stop this process without manually pressing Ctrl+C

Comment: don't use .system. use a pipe so the external app runs independently of python. e.g. .system() blocks and won't return until whatever external command you're executing exits.

Comment: Check out [pyserial](https://github.com/pyserial/pyserial).

Answer (score 1):

If you spawn the process with

```
child = subprocess.Popen("command")
```

Then you can call

```
child.terminate()
child.kill()
```

- [0] https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen
- [1] https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects